# App enters unknown/locked state after handling UnhandledException

Tags: c#, wpf, unhandled-exception

In my App.xaml.cs I have events to handle DispatcherUnhandledExceptions (UI thread) and UnhandledException (Non UI thread). When I throw an exception inside dispatcher.Invoke, the dispatcherhandler catches the exception and handles it. I am setting e.Handled to true after logging the exception. Now the strange behaviour, if i throw the exception outside of the dispatcher.Invoke as a regualr statment, control is sent to the dispatcher exception handler,but after the method is processed the app basically loses control but I can tell its still running by looking at the stop button in vs.

one more thing, if i set e.handled to false, control is sent to the non-ui thread exception handler.

So what puzzles me is why is the application locking after handling the exceptiono in the dispatcher handler?

here's my code

```
    private void App_DispatcherUnhandledException(object sender, DispatcherUnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
       // log exception here
        e.Handled = true; 
    } // control is lost after executing this block

    private void App_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            Exception ex = e.ExceptionObject as Exception;                
            // log exception here
        }
        finally
        {
            Environment.Exit(-1);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

An UnhandledException means that your application is effectively dead. If you get that event then it is too late to do anything to recover from the scenario. Typically you would use this event only to log errors for debugging purposes and maybe attempt to cleanup some unmanaged resources.

The following [article](http://firstchanceexception.com/2011/09/19/wpf-exceptionhandling/) gives a detailed explanation of exception handling in WPF.

Comment: but why does the app enter a vegetable state after executing e.handled= true? In my window constructor, I am throwing exception , throw new Exception("some exception"). control is sent to the dispatcherUnhandledException handler, but the app still keeps  running.

Comment: I would not recommend throwing exceptions from a window constructor. Instead put your logic in the Initialized or Loaded event instead and then kill yourself as a window.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the app is able to resume operation if the exception is raised after the OnStartup Event, if the exception is raised in between, the exception is caught and handled but the main window is never shown yet the debugger shows the app as running.

the closest solution I found is to remove complex logic from the constructor of main window to allow onstartup event to execute and do a lot of loading in my MainWindow load event.